# Serve static content(Single page application) using Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, single-page-application, wildfly-10, undertow

I need to serve static content outside of WAR using the Wildfly application server.
I setup

```
   <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
   </host>
    <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="c:/Users/admin/web" directory-listing="true"/>
            </handlers>
```

Everything worked okay but I faced with the routing problem.
The application has a html5 history support.
When I go to the Url: localhost:8080 everything is okay, my app redirects to /home
But when I refresh the page it returns 404 error.

Is there a possibility to define location name as wildcard e.g. /* 
 or how can i solve the problem with single page application?